# How to send multiple files to server in android?

Tags: java, android, file, fileinputstream, multipartentity

Good day to all. I am having clarification about to send multiple files to server. I have completed that send single file to server. Below code is detail about send single file to server.

```
private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;
public String TAG = "MainActivity";
Uri uri;
String path = null, filename;
File filede;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        fileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fileName);
        filePath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filePath);
        fileCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fileCount);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnup);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadFile(path, filename);
            }
        });
    }
```

Once we called show file chooser method i have to intent to add category and with in the activity result i have to file name, file and file path. that activity result is

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("file/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"),
                FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install a File Manager.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.e(TAG, "File Uri: " + uri.toString());
                // Get the path

                path = FilePath.getPath(MainActivity.this, uri);
                filede = new File(path);
                filename = filede.getName();
                Log.e(TAG, "File Path: " + path);
                Log.e(TAG, "File: " + filede);
                Log.e(TAG, "File filename: " + filename);


            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

With  the help of file path and file name i have uploaded file to server.

```
 private void uploadFile(String filePath, String fileName) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File filename:----------->uploadFile "+filePath+", "+fileName);
        InputStream inputStream;


        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
            Log.e(TAG, "File inputStream:-----------> "+inputStream);
            byte[] data;
            try {
                data = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
                Log.e(TAG, "File data:-----------> "+data);
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("Your URL");
                Log.e(TAG, "File httpPost:-----------> "+httpPost);
                InputStreamBody inputStreamBody = new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), fileName);

                Log.e(TAG, "File inputStreamBody:-----------> "+inputStreamBody);
                MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();

                multipartEntity.addPart("fileContent0", inputStreamBody);
                multipartEntity.addPart("id", new StringBody("331"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("fileCount",  new StringBody("1"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("fileType", new StringBody("SAMPLE"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("platform", new StringBody("Android"));
                multipartEntity.addPart("externalID", new StringBody(""));
                httpPost.addHeader("Authorization","");
                Log.e(TAG, "File multipartEntity:-----------> "+multipartEntity);
                httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                Log.e(TAG, "File httpResponse:----------->httpResponse "+httpResponse.getStatusLine());

                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                JSONObject o = new JSONObject(result.toString());


                Log.e("oooooo","ooooooo------------------>"+o);
                // Handle response back from script.
                if (httpResponse != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "File httpResponse111:----------->httpResponse11 "+httpResponse);
                } else { // Error, no response.

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("error","error--------->"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here i am passing single file name and single file path for uploading single file. **Actually my requirement is i have to pass multiple file name and multiple file path. And How to store file path and file name into an array list when each file has selected separately?** 
 And how to get the multiple file response from server.
Thanks in advance friends. Kindly please review it and help me.

Comment: Can you try with retrofit2

Comment: No i didn't try with retrofit2. Does we can't possible to send multiple files with the help of my code? @Saveen

Comment: Yes you can send it in partmap

Comment: You send it also this code it already deprecated .So , you have got many  problem